# How can we specify width for each tab in tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using tabhost in my application. Can we give separate width property for each tab? i.e, one with larger width and other with smaller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can mention the tab width in code like:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 50;
```

Comment: Don't forget to stay device independent, use DisplayMetrics.density to correct your hardcoded pixel value to a `dp` value.

Answer (score 4):

I tried below code and it worked perfectly fine for me

```
LayoutParams params = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams();
params.width = 170;
params.height = 120;
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(params );
```

you can change width and height as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

For your reference, if the parent layout of theTabWidget is LinearLayout, then you may need also to set the weight of the child LayoutParams. Since the tabs stretch its width in my case as its default weight is 1.0.

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams()).weight = 0;
```