# How can we specify width for each tab in tabhost android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I am using tabhost in my application. Can we give separate width property for each tab? i.e, one with larger width and other with smaller?please give me sample example.if possible means give me code.

**EDIT:**

```
public class TabBarSimple extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    TabSpec dbspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("DashBoard");
    dbspec.setIndicator("Dashboard", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dashboard));

    Intent dbIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    dbspec.setContent(dbIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(dbspec);

    TabSpec orderspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Orders");
    orderspec.setIndicator("Orders", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orders));

    Intent orderIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
    orderspec.setContent(orderIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(orderspec);
    TabSpec settingspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Customers");
    settingspec.setIndicator("Customers", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.customers));
    Intent settingIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
    settingspec.setContent(settingIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(settingspec);
    TabSpec aboutspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings");
    aboutspec.setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings));
    Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    aboutspec.setContent(aboutIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(aboutspec);
    TabSpec logoutspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Logout");
    logoutspec.setIndicator("Logout", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logout));
    Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
    logoutspec.setContent(logoutIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(logoutspec);


    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
    //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 100;
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().width = 50;
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
    //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);

     }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
          TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
    //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
    }
    //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
    }

     }
```

Comment: look at this [prev. answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801825/how-can-we-specify-width-for-each-tab-in-tabhost

Comment: See this example http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: @Omar Johari : i added that line.but i got the following error on my console window:10-09 16:48:46.796: E/AndroidRuntime(2923): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 16:48:46.796: E/AndroidRuntime(2923):  at com.example.androidtablayout.TabBarSimple.onCreate(TabBarSimple.java:30)
10-09 16:48:46.796: E/AndroidRuntime(2923):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: @BBdev  i have used already this tutorial.here am faced following problem.please give me solution for this asked question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794088/tablayout-set-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by the code below -:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 50;
```

Comment: i added the above line.but i got the following error on my console window:10-09 16:48:46.796: E/AndroidRuntime(2923): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 10-09 16:48:46.796: E/AndroidRuntime(2923): at com.example.androidtablayout.TabBarSimple.onCreate(TabBarSimple.java:30) 10-09 16:48:46.796: E/AndroidRuntime(2923): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: This is bad way, because width is in pixels.

Comment: In case the accepted answer is not good enough for you and you are using custom views for tabhost indicators, try to set weightSum on tabhost view and then proper layout_weight param on your own indicator views (all in xml). 
You can of course set layout_weight on default indicator views but that requires a little coding.